# Math Functions With Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Each time I click a button on my site I would like to 'updateDoc' increase the value of the number in the database with something similar the the Javascript ++

I was wondering if this is possible and if its not what else can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore has a [`increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) function that you can use to increment a field while updating a document.

```
import { doc, updateDoc, increment } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "collection", "DOC_ID");

await updateDoc(docRef, {
    field_name: increment(1)
});
```